# Unit Test a C function with HW interaction

Tags: c++, unit-testing, esp32, platformio

Hi I am working on C project for ESP32 using the platformio enviroment.
I am using the unity test framework provided from the platformio env.
I would like to unit test the following function

```
float reading_board_temp(void)
{
    uint32_t adc_reading = 0;
    float board_temp = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < NO_OF_SAMPLES; i++) 
    {
        
        adc_reading += adc1_get_raw((adc1_channel_t)adc_1_ch_board_temp);
        vTaskDelay(TEN_TICKS_DELAY);
  
    }
    adc_reading /= NO_OF_SAMPLES;
    uint32_t voltage = esp_adc_cal_raw_to_voltage(adc_reading, adc_chars_board_temp);
    board_temp = (voltage - MCP9700AT_OFFSET)/TEMP_DIVIDER; 
    return board_temp;
    
}
```

This is the test file I have created always in platformio

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <unity.h>
#include <gpioa_module.h>

void test_board_temp() 
{
     float expected_temp  = 35; 
     float risult_reading = 0;

     risult_reading =  reading_board_temp ();  

     TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL(expected_temp, risult_reading);
}

void setUp(void)
{

}
void tearDown(void)
{

}
void setup() 
{
    // NOTE!!! Wait for >2 secs
    // if board doesn't support software reset via Serial.DTR/RTS
    delay(2000);

    UNITY_BEGIN();
    RUN_TEST(test_board_temp);
    RUN_TEST(test_example2);
    UNITY_END();
}

void loop() 
{

}
```

When I try to test in the esp32 it seems to freeze.

How can I test the function removing or faking the hw dependancies ?

Thanks a lot for your kind reply.

Comment: Only answering in comment, because I do not know you hardware platform and its library. C does not allow to use simple *mocks* like we would use for Java programs. What I did when I was younger was to build a stub library with the same functions as the hardware one (but hardcoded responses...), and I linked the test application with that stub library. Unsure whether it is relevant for your actual use case...

Comment: Agree on @SergeBallesta – you want to test that function with very specific input – trying to produce that with HW attached will render problematic unless you can provoke specific values in some kind of simulation mode (which is rather unlikely...).

Comment: By the way, if you prefer commercial rounding you might use `adc_reading = (adc_reading + NO_OF_SAMPLES / 2) / NO_OF_SAMPLES;` instead...

Answer (score 0):

So guys you are suggesting to do something like this

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "gpioa_module_test.h"


float reading_board_temp_test(void)
{

    uint32_t adc_reading = 0;
    float board_temp = 0;
    uint32_t raw_vaue = 34;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
    {
        
        adc_reading += raw_vaue;
       
  
    }

    adc_reading /= 10;
    uint32_t voltage = adc_reading / 10;
    board_temp = (voltage - 500)/10; 
    return board_temp;
        
}
```

and now the test part become

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <unity.h>
#include <gpioa_module_test.h>

void test_board_temp() 
{
     float expected_temp  = 35; 
     float risult_reading = 0;

     risult_reading =  reading_board_temp_test ();  

     TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL(expected_temp, risult_reading);
}
```

Comment: correct - Serge Ballesta